# How do I render country name from country_id in Adminhtml grids?

Tags: admin, adminhtml, grid, renderer, country-regions

Is there a built-in column renderer for that, or should I build one myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the customer grid, there is an internal column renderer `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Country`.

Comment: I'm just not sure if `Mage::app()->getLocale()->getCountryTranslation($country_code)` will get the whole name or simply does CSV translations.

Comment: ANY OTHER CHANGED REQUIRED ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a folder GRID/FILTER/COUNTRY from your grid.php folder

Add a file Country.php with the following code:

```
class YourComapny_YourModule_Block_Adminhtml_YourGridName_Grid_Filter_Country extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Select
{

protected function _getOptions()
    {
        $options = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->load()->toOptionArray();
        array_unshift($options, array('value'=>'', 'label'=>$this->__('All countries')));
        return $options;
    }
}
```

In your Grid.php set the country column to:

```
    $this->addColumn(
        'country_code',
        array(
            'header'=> $this->__('Country Code'),
            'width' => '5px',
            'type'  => 'country',
            'index' => 'country_code'
        )
    );
```